# mySQL 5.5 syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the syntax shown below for MySQL 5.5

```
$sql = "select tm.*, tt.tax_rate as tax from ".TABLE_MEMBER." tm left join ".TABLE_TAX_RATES." tt on tt.tax_rates_id = tm.rent_tax_class_id where plan_id='".$planid."'";
$rs = tep_db_query($sql);
$row_days = tep_db_fetch_array($rs);
if (!$row_days['tax']) $row_days['tax'] = 0;
```

Comment: will you show us Error..?

Comment: Is `TABLE_MEMBER` a PHP Constant?

Comment: missing semicolon at last line? :D

Comment: You didn't even post what the syntax error message was, although I'm going to have to go with @Console as well as Hanky.

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as tax from membership tm left join tax_rates tt on tt.tax_rates_id = tm.rent_ta' at line 1

select tm.*, tt.* as tax from membership tm left join tax_rates tt on tt.tax_rates_id = tm.rent_tax_class_id where plan_id='1'

[TEP STOP]

Answer (score 1):

`tt.* AS` is invalid syntax because you cannot alias multiple columns.  You have to write out each column individually (and alias those as needed), or simply accept using `*`, which you should avoid using in production.  The query in your comment is different from the one in your question which should not cause this error.

You should also be using properly parameterized queries -- your query is vulnerable to injection.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to mention table alias in where clause

The sql should be

```
$sql = "select tm.*, tt.tax_rate as tax from ".TABLE_MEMBER." tm left join ".TABLE_TAX_RATES." tt on tt.tax_rates_id = tm.rent_tax_class_id where tm.plan_id='".$planid."'";
```

or

```
$sql = "select tm.*, tt.tax_rate as tax from ".TABLE_MEMBER." tm left join ".TABLE_TAX_RATES." tt on tt.tax_rates_id = tm.rent_tax_class_id where tt.plan_id='".$planid."'";
```